# Question about durability of a hardtail

Tags: mountain-bike, dirt-jumps

Having an mtb hardtail KTM ultra fire 27.5 (2015 model year) I wonder what it’s capable of in terms of jumping. I do get that it’s not designed for things of such sort but still want to know more details. I’ve found bike classification with description on KTM website( https://www.ktm-bikes.at/bike-category) and it seems like an answer to my questions but not really as I don’t know the category of the bike I have. So I looked up the category of new hardtails they sell ( they no longer sell ultra fire but Ig ultra flite is kinda the same) and assumed that my bike is also of the 3 rd category. Do you think this type of reasoning is sensible? Ig yes as mine and new ultra flite share the same alloy 6601 frame. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3):

How long a bike lasts is made up of a combination of many factors. Here are a few:

1. Frame designed and built quality
2. Component designed and build quality
3. How you ride

I'm sure there are others...
**The most important factor is how you ride.**
The most amazingly built bike can be destroyed on one ride.

Some people have a feel for how to keep from destroying a bike and others don't
Some people land a jump soft, others land hard - every time.
How you land a jump is just one example of off-road riding style.

Generally, people who are just learning jumping are harder on bikes than people who have experience.

We can't tell you how durable your bike will be.

Comment: Add maintenance to the list of important things for durability/longevity. Forks come to mind as something that can be destroyed by poor Maintenance.

Comment: Got it, are there any general recommendations about maintenance? Ig there should be some. My bike was never maintain 8 years straight haha, the only thing I did is replaced rear break pads as old ones were completely worn out. Looks like it’s time to change cassette as well as chain. I wonder if there is a need in changing front cassete after replacement of the chain and  rear one?

Answer (score 1):

Having a read over the description on the website looks to me like these are cross country bikes.  Normally these sit in Category 3 but can't see anything specific on the site.

Category 3 can do some jumps and things, but not really designed for hunting out massive jumps, more small drops that you would normally find on cross country trails. With great technique and execution every time, it will be fine on slightly bigger hits but not a huge margin for error.